# Robocopy: <Source>

Tags: cmd, archive, robocopy

I am trying to create a .cmd script to archive my project folders in SharePoint using robocopy. The issue that I am having is that there are many folders in the source dir that I do not want to archive.

```
@set sourcepath=\\foo\bar\p_*
```

I prepended my project folders with 'p_' so I could set my source variable to /foo/bar/p_*. This way I would pick up each folder and all of it's files without grabbing all of the other 'non-project' folders. Obviously this did not work.

Is there a way to pull this off without having to build a folder list that I need to manage every time a project folder is added?

Your input is appreciated

Comment: did you try **robocopy /?** it has exclude option ....

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of directories with a command.

```
dir /A:D /B /r p_*
```

Then you can use a FOR loop to start robocopy for each directory.

```
SETLOCAL
SET SOURCEDIR=\\source\...
SET DESTINATIONDIR=\\dest\...
CD %SOURCEDIR%
FOR /F %%G IN ('dir /A:D /B /r p_*') DO robocopy "%SOURCEDIR%\%%G" "%DESTINATIONDIR%\%%G" /e
```